How can I map a path to different domain name in API Gateway?
I have a single API Gateway, and I want to map requests so that a different custom domain triggers the same API but with part of the path stripped out. Essentially I want api.example.com/<any-path> to be be equivalent to www.example.com/api/public/<any-path>. Is this possible with API Gateway?
I've already tried the Custom Path attribute of the API mapping in the custom domain settings, but that doesn't do what I'm looking for it. It still requires the /public/api/ section of the path.
